# How to create an ephemeral user-level systemd timer on the commandline without unit/timer files?

Tags: linux, command-line, systemd, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

Suppose I want to run the command `notify-send "invoked" "$(date)"` every 5 seconds using systemd timers.

I know how to create a corresponding unit file and a timer file, then `enable` the timer for user, but I want a pure CLI-based solution.

I want to simply do the above in commandline without needing to create 2 files. Something like: `systemd-blah enable my_command --every 5s`.

Comment: Comment, because my answer is a bit off target: why not `while true; do notify-send ...; sleep 5; done`?

Comment: @Malik same reason as answers provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/cron-vs-sleep-which-is-the-better-one-in-terms-of-efficient-cpu-memory-utiliz).
I'm starting multiple tasks like this and I want to get a list of tasks in queue using systemd's functionality. BTW, the same thing could be achieved with `watch`: `watch -n5 my_command`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`systemd-run`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html), specifically one of the timer-related options: [`--on-active=, --on-boot=, --on-startup=, --on-unit-active=, --on-unit-inactive=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html#--on-active=) and [`--on-calendar=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html#--on-calendar=).

Using a monotonic timer:

```bsh
systemd-run --user --on-startup=0s --on-unit-inactive=5s --timer-property=AccuracySec=100ms sh -c 'notify-send "invoked" "$(date)"'
```

Using a calendar (wall-clock) timer:

```bsh
systemd-run --user --on-calendar='*:*:0/5' --timer-property=AccuracySec=100ms sh -c 'notify-send "invoked" "$(date)"'
```

Note that the default timer accuracy is 1 minute, which is too coarse for timer intervals as short as 5 seconds.

Other useful arguments to `systemd-run` you will likely want to use include [`--unit`/`-u`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html#--unit=) (for naming the unit) and [`--description`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html#--description=) (for providing a description that is shown by systemd, in the journal, etc. instead of the triggered command).

The transient systemd units behave just like regular ones. Once they are no longer referenced anywhere, they are garbage collected as described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20Garbage%20Collection).

Comment: Thanks! How can I make it persistent (survive restart/shutdown)?

Comment: Either put `systemd-run --user --unit=foo ...` in your shell's init script (discarding the error message shown if the unit already exists) or better, create the appropriate units in `~/.config/systemd/user/` yourself (i.e. `foo.service` and an associated `foo.timer`). For detailed information I recommend looking at the related [Arch Linux Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User). Most information in that article is not specific to Arch.